# Combination of a range of numbers consecutively

Tags: c#, numbers, combinations

I want to find the combination for a range of numbers in a consecutive manner. 
Suppose I have a range of numbers from 1 to 5 then my list of the combinations will be like {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {1,2} {1,2,3} {1,2,3,4} {1,2,3,4,5} {2,3} {2,3,4} {2,3,4,5} {3,4} {3,4,5} {4,5}.

However, my list should not include combinations like {1,3,4,5} {1,5} {2,5} etc. It should have the numbers in each set consecutively.

I have tried this by adding a Left Pad to the list. In this case, it is also considering the non-consecutive set also.

```
        double count = Math.Pow(2, list.Count);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
        {
            string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(list.Count, '0');

            for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
            {


                if (str[j] == '1')
                {
                    Console.Write(list[j]);

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Your question makes sense, but it's not clear why you suddenly start padding strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < range.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j <= range.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", range[i..j]));
    }
}
```

If you're not using C# 8 (and so you can't use ranges), then you can use `Skip()` and `Take()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < range.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j <= range.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", range.Skip(i).Take(j-i)));
    }
}
```

Note that this prints {1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {2} etc instead of {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {1,2} etc. If this is important, you can tweak it like this:

```
foreach (var item in range)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);    
}

for (int i = 0; i < range.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+2; j <= range.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", range.Skip(i).Take(j-i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it will - the number of combinations goes up a lot as the number of inputs increases!

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider accepting / upvoting it

Comment: However, the sets are repeating. For example, if the set is from 1 to 3 then the output is    1
1
1,2
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3
2
2
2,3
2,3
3
3    Anyways, thank you.

Comment: @user3812657 That's not true? See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AGitca

Comment: My bad, you are right. I was trying with both list and array in the for loop. Sorry about that.